# How to POST to Spring Boot Actuator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I issue the following:

```
curl localhost:8080/actuator/env -d'{"name":"test",value:"hello world!"}' -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

I get:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-03-09T16:21:18.245+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/actuator/env
```

My application.yml file exposes the endpoint and I can issue a GET request without any issue:

```
management:
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: "*"
```

I do **not** have Spring Security enabled. How can I enable submission of POST requests to Spring Actuator endpoints? I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.5.

Comment: you can configure many things about `spring.management.*` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#actuator-properties) ..but this(to change the endpoints http method) actually (i fear) is not possible.

Comment: I'm reading a book that states the `/env` endpoint (as well as other such as `/loggers`) supports `POST` requests. But that is actually not so? So, for example, I cannot change the logging level of a certain logger during runtime? I thought that was one of the primary benefits of using Spring Actuator.

Comment: according to current doc: Each endpoint has its distinct(set of) http method(s) and it doesn't suggest to be configurable. Maybe it was true in earlier versions. The [env-endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#env) - `GET`. `POST` is only offered by ["rebuilding integrationgraph"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#integrationgraph-rebuilding), [loggers(set/reset)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#loggers)

Comment: ..and [shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#shutdown-shutting-down)

Comment: Ah. OK. I can post to logger and change the logging level. There might have been a change to the env endpoint. The book that I'm referencing is Spring in Action 5th edition page 407-408. Thanks for the links.

Comment: ...until someone proofs me wrong! :)

Comment: hmh, the book is quite actual, and really states that `/env` offers `GET, POST, DELETE` ..which is not conform with spring-doc ..and also not with the experienced behavior (as you posted).  I think "errata" in book printing is as common as "bugs" in software development:)  ...and the latest/best/ environment-/runtime-specific information, you can get is by (enabling&) issuing: ["mappings" endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#mappings) ...it returns you all registered http mappings including actuator.

Comment: When considering ["custom endpoint section"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom), and looking at [actuator-sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/env/EnvironmentEndpoint.java) ... `EnvironmentEndpoint` never (not after Sept. 2017: move to github) had any `@Write-` or `@DeleteOperation`s  - so offered no POST/DELETE endpoints.

Answer (score 7):

In the current versions(2.2.5+) of spring boot exposing the env endpoint is not enough if you want to update/set the environment property while the application is running.

You have to set

```
management.endpoint.env.post.enabled=true
```

After this you can update the property by using the below command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"foo", "value":"bar"}' http://localhost:8080/my-application/actuator/env
```

Comment: spring boot does not recognize such property in 2.2.6

Comment: This is surprisingly difficult property to track down. It works well for Spring boot 2.4.4, Spring cloud 2020.0.2. Also this property is not even listed here currently: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Comment: Also this issue explains what is going on: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20509